# How to pass pipeline credential parameter to python script as env variable

Tags: python, shell, credentials, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline job with a credential parameter (user name and password), and also a groovy file that runs a shell script which triggers python file.
How can I pass those parameters to the env so the python script can use them with os.getenv?
Groovy file code:

```
def call() {
    final fileContent = libraryResource('com/amdocs/python_distribution_util/main.py')
    writeFile file: 'main.py', text: fileContent

    sh "python main.py"}
```

I know the pipeline-syntax should look something similar to that:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '*****', passwordVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_SERVICE_ID_PW', usernameVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_SERVICE_ID_UN')]) {
    // some block
}
```

what is the correct way for doing it?

[image: credential parameter from the jenkins pipeline]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax:

```
def call() {
        def DISTRIBUTION_CREDENTIAL_ID = params.DISTRIBUTION_CREDENTIAL_ID

        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: '${DISTRIBUTION_CREDENTIAL_ID}', passwordVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_SERVICE_ID_PW',  usernameVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_SERVICE_ID_UN')]) {
        sh '''
            export ARTIFACTORY_SERVICE_ID_UN=${ARTIFACTORY_SERVICE_ID_UN}
            export ARTIFACTORY_SERVICE_ID_PW=${ARTIFACTORY_SERVICE_ID_PW}
    }
}
```

and then you can use config.py file to pull the values using:

```
import os

ARTIFACTORY_SERVICE_ID_UN = os.getenv('ARTIFACTORY_SERVICE_ID_UN')
ARTIFACTORY_SERVICE_ID_PW = os.getenv('ARTIFACTORY_SERVICE_ID_PW')
```

Comment: This gets the masked content to the code. How did you get the actual value? I get just a string of asterisks.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: any solution for this?